# convert string to int not using int() in python

Tags: python, int

I need to convert from string to `int`, but I can't use `int()` or `float()`. This is the code that I've been thinking to use but it doesn't work because `R[0]` is also an string.

The code works if I change

```
num = R[longitud-longitud]
```

to:

```
num = float(R[longitud-longitud])
```

My code:

```
def string2num_aux(R,longitud,F):
    if longitud == 0:
        return F
    else:
        num = R[longitud-longitud]
        val = num*10**(longitud-1)
        return string2num_aux(R[1:],longitud-1,F+val)
```

Comment: Why can't use you use int or float?

Comment: why do you need `longitud - longitud`, isn't that `0`?

Comment: I can't use it because I'm in the college learning python and the idea is to use recursivity.

Comment: And longitud - longitud obviously is 0 but this is a copy/paste from a test and must be exactly as I wrote it.

Comment: @KendallGonzález Next time you have a college assignment: try to sort things out alone. The whole point is most probably to make you solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you may use `ord` function, return an integer representing the Unicode code point of the character

```
def string2num_aux(R,longitud,F):
  if longitud == 0:
    return F
  else:
    num = R[0]                                     #longitud-longitud is unneccesary
    val = (ord(num)-ord('0'))*10**(longitud-1)     #Line change
    return string2num_aux(R[1:],longitud-1,F+val)

string2num_aux("12345",5,0)
```

you get

> 12345

code improve:

```
def string2num_aux(R):
  if len(R) == 0:
    return 0
  else:
    num = R[0]
    val = (ord(num)-ord('0'))*10**(len(R)-1)
    return val + string2num_aux(R[1:])

string2num_aux("12345")
```

without `ord`, i use a dictionary

```
d={"0":0, "1":1, "2":2, "3":3, "4":4, "5":5, "6":6, "7":7, "8":8, "9":9}

def string2num_aux(R):
  if len(R) == 0:
    return 0
  else:
    num = R[0]
    val = d[num]*10**(len(R)-1)
    return val + string2num_aux(R[1:])

string2num_aux("12345")
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure if I can user built-in function like "ord" but thank you